# Showing that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

Separately, I can show that both parts of the sum diverge, but that doesn't help me very much. I don't see any test which could come in handy. I know both sides of the sum have popular Taylor forms, so I can partially represent them as such around $x=0$, but my question then what do I do with the remainder?

Comment: Hint: Compute $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x}{\sin(x^2)-\ln(1+x)}$

Comment: @MatthewPilling You get this from comparing the entire sequence to $1/n$ (shouldn't you also have $x^2$ at the numerator?), which I didn't think of doing since it didn't look like the two parts have a constant sign after a certain point. Any immediate giveaways that they do?

Comment: I'm suggesting you use LCT with $$a_n=\sin\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)-\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)$$ $$b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Heh, silly me. I compared with $1/n$ and ended up doing some extra L'Hospitals. Regardless, doesn't the fact that the sequence doesn't have a constant sign pose a problem with applying the LCT?

Comment: It turns out $a_n$ ia negative for all $n>1$. So maybe use LCT with $-a_n$ and $b_n$ to show that $\sum_{n\geq 2} -a_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{split}\sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\right)&=\left[\frac 1 n +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n^3}\right)\right]-\left[\frac 1 {\sqrt n}-\frac 1 {2n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n\sqrt n}\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac 1 {\sqrt n}+\frac 3 {2n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n\sqrt n}\right)\\
&\sim -\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\end{split}$$